# Error when converting date to dd-MMM-yy

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting an error when I run the following line of code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(bolShipdate, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
```

The error is:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The bolShipdate value is 02-21-2016. I need to convert the date to 21-Feb-16.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well you're trying to *parse* it with that pattern... you need to parse it specifying the existing pattern, then *format* it in the new pattern.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Others have already done so. But it's really important that you understand what's going on here - `DateTime.ParseExact` just converts a `string` to a `DateTime`. After that, the `DateTime` has no knowledge of what pattern was originally used.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration of `DateTime.ParseExact` is

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

Here you will want to pass the format you are parsing not the expected result. And it looks like your string is of the format `MM-dd-yyyy`.
You can then use `.ToString(string format` to get the date in your desired format:

```
string date = "02-21-2016";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newFormat = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
Console.WriteLine(newFormat);
```

Comment: Except it looks like it's `MM-dd-yyyy`. I'd also recommend using the invariant culture.

Comment: I tried using invariant culture, but I get the same error message

Comment: @user990423 Edit gives "21-Feb-16"

Comment: @SimonKarlsson, using your edited code, gives the same error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @user990423 What about if you use that full example? (new edit)

Answer (score 2):

Your format in `ParseExact` needs to match your string. `dd/MMM/yyyy` doesn't match the sample data provided. try:

```
    var bolShipdate = "02-21-2016";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(bolShipdate, "MM-dd-yyyy", null);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")); // Dispays 21-Feb-16
```

([Example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JSVUwx))

Comment: strangely, your code also returns the same error message

Comment: @user990423 Did you run the fiddle provided?

Comment: @user990423 then you have something else going on with your system, as you can see the code works :-) Try specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of null on the parse as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can resolve:

```
var date = "02-21-2016";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```